# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and Holder’s inequality

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $f, g \in L^2([-\pi , \pi ], \mu , \mathbb{R} )$ then I have already showed that $$ \int |fg| \,{\rm d} \mu \leq \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 $$ and I have shown that this is an equality if and only if $|f|=c|g|$ almost everywhere or $\|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 =0$.

Now I have showed that $$ \left| \int fg \,{\rm d} \mu \right| \leq \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 $$ and I am trying to show that this is an equality if and only if $f=cg$ almost everywhere or $\|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 =0$.

Now I know that $$\left| \int fg \,{\rm d} \mu \right| \leq \int |fg| \,{\rm d} \mu \leq \|f\|_2 \|g\|_2$$ and so these all must be equalities so I know that from the equality on the right, we must have $ |f|=c|g| $ almost everywhere or $\|f\|_2 \|g\|_2 =0$ but then with the equality on the right hand side I need to show that this means that $f=cg$ almost everywhere but I’m not sure how.

Comment: Equality on the left holds if $fg$ has constant sign $\mu$-a.e.